# Windows Phone: Upload Progress

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

I've built a Windows Phone app that needs to upload an image to a server. I'd like to display an upload progress percentage instead of the generic progress bar.

I'm uploading the images as Byte[] to my server using a WCF service (basitHttpBinding).

Has anyone managed to do this yet?

Answer (score -1):

On WebRequest or WebClient this would be easier but since you're using WCF guess we have to take another approach!

Please check if [this approach](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20364/Progress-Indication-while-Uploading-Downloading-Fi) will work for you!

Note that this approach uses a Stream when sending/receiving, that shouldn't be an issue given that internally it will be converted to a byte array (like you have).